# Ajax code not working only validation worked

Tags: ajax

[Here is the JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qref356z/4/)

My Ajax code not working i dont know how..
I used ajax below code many time but this time not working
please help me..

**only this code run inside the ajax code**

```
if(!validateee()) return false;
```

**If validation code remove then ajax run**

**Ajax Code**

```
$('#body-enquiry').submit(function(e){  
              e.preventDefault(); 
            if(!validateee()) return false; 
             $(this).find(":submit").prop("disabled", true); 

            var form = $(this);  
            var post_url = 'enquiry-entire-mail.php';  
            var post_data = form.serialize();  
            $.ajax({  
                type: 'POST',  
                url: post_url,   
                data: post_data, 

                success: function(data) {  
                    alert('Submited');
                }  


            }); 

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to return true at the end of your function that is the issue.

```
 return true;
```

this you need to write in you `validateee` function .

please find update here : https://jsfiddle.net/qref356z/6/

you updated `validateee` function, update below code it will work i checked it at my end

```
      function validateee() {
            var name = document.popbody.namebody.value;
            var email = document.popbody.emailbody.value;
            var number = document.popbody.numberbody.value.length;
            var msg = document.popbody.msgbody.value.length;
            alert('msg5');
            if(name.trim() == "") {
                alert("Please Fill Name");
                document.popbody.namebody.focus();
                return false;
            }
            alert('msg4');
            if(name<3) {
                alert("invalid Name");
                document.popbody.namebody.focus();
                return false;
            }
            alert('msg3');
            if(email=="") {
                alert("Enter Your Email");
                document.popbody.emailbody.focus();
                return false;
            }
            alert('msg2');
            if(number=="") {
                alert("Enter Your Number");
                document.popbody.numberbody.focus();
                return false;
            }
            alert('msg1');
            if(number<9) {
                alert("Your Mobile number at least 10 digit");
                document.popbody.numberbody.focus();
                return false;
            }
            alert('msg');
            if(msg == "") {
                alert("Enter your Message");
                document.popbody.msgbody.focus();
                return false;
            }

    return true;///you need to add here 
  }
```

Comment: @Inderjeet - please check here : https://jsfiddle.net/qref356z/6/ this is working buddy ...it reached till ajax function ...now i dont know what is your url